# How to properly use the URL with Kotlin Android

Tags: android, json, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I want to use

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val json = URL("https://my-api-url.com/something").readText()
    simpleTextView.setText(json)
}
```

but this fatal error occurs

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mypackage.randompackage, PID: 812
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ ***.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

How can I simply read a JSON from a URL link?
The package of the `async` function  doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android doesn't allow accessing the internet from the main thread.
The simplest way around this would be to open the URL on a background thread.

Something like this:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute({
            val json = URL("https://my-api-url.com/something").readText()
            simpleTextView.post { simpleTextView.text = json }
        })
```

Don't forget to register Internet permission in the Android Manifest file.

Comment: In case anyone wanted to know what exactly to put into the Android Manifest file, this is what worked for me.    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  It goes within the <manifest> tags but outside the <application> tag

Comment: Nice simple solution without adding dependencies. Its pretty shocking how fragmented online docs are on trying to do something simple like this in kotlin - I tried to get anko and the kotlin coroutines to work without any success.

Comment: It's taken me hours to find a solution to my simple problem, this was it, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use coroutines:

```
val json = async(UI) {
        URL("https://my-api-url.com/something").readText()
    }
```

Remember to add coroutines to build.gradle:

```
kotlin {
experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
...
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinx_coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlinx_coroutines_version"
...
}
```

[Coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md) are brilliant.